# Looking for Davit family in Sibiu between 1875 and 1900

Tags: birth-records, baptism-records, romania

My great grandmother immigrated to the US from Romania around 1900.  She identified her nationality as German in all the census she answered.

I am assuming she came from Sibiu but I don't know for sure.  Her name was Kathrine (or Catherine) Davit.

I don't know where to start looking for her family.

Comment: Rick Courtney - Do you mean Sibiu county or the city of Sibiu? What clues do you have for her birthplace? The question linked by the moderators will only help if you already have a specific location but you will need to do more research if you don't. David is a Transylvanian-Saxon surname in a couple of villages; Davit may be a rarer variation.

Comment: Thank you bgwiehle.  I don't  don't know if it is the county or city.  I am speculating Sibiu because she said she was from Romanian and was German.  Is there a data base of marriages, births, and deaths from 1890 back I can query?

Comment: There are a growing # of online resources available, but you need to at least know the region (and preferably, the religion). _When_ did she (or the record) say she was from Romania - If it was before 1918, then she could be from Wallachia. If after 1918, when Romania took over a lot of former Hungarian territory, then Transylvania & other regions are possible. Germans had pockets of settlement all over Europe. You may be able edit your question to add details of what you know -- what records you've searched or found, if there were any extended family in contact, even mis-spelled clues, etc.